# Google interfaces and files

Tags: c++, naming-conventions

I use Google C++ code style. But I don't know how to name interfaces and files for these interfaces.

Google file names is `class_name.h`, but what is name for class ICommand, for example? i_command.h or icommand.h or command_interface.h? Someone know how does google names it?

Comment: https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html I literally just Googled "Google style guide". Two clicks later.

Comment: @sweenish your link doesn't specify which rule indicates file naming rule for interfaces. I assume OP has read [File_Names](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#File_Names) but it doesn't specify for class or interface.

Comment: No, but it's all there. Feel free to find it and post an answer if you want. The information isn't hiding, and it's not as difficult to navigate as the C++ standard.

Answer (score 0):

C++ does not have built-in interfaces so Google code style does not specify their naming.
I think they use the same convention for file names as for all other classes.
https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/main/pdf/paint_manager.h